# Google plus api not valid access token exception

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm working with Google+ API and here's what I got. I know that the access token may become invalid in case of the user uninstalling App or de-authorizing it. But I couldn't find how to handle that case. Is it going to throw an exception? If so, what exact exception (maybe someone knows the code)?
I thought that it might be possible to get an http error code like 404 (unauthorized)? If it is, how do I get it?
Here is some code:

```
try {
   $me = $plus->people->get('me')
} catch (Exception $e) {
     // Maybe do something with the error code from $e->getCode();
}
```

Or check the code obtained from I don't know where:

```
if($code == 401) {
    throw new Exception('Expired access token detected. Mailing to admin.', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the http status from $e->getCode()

Comment: Also, make sure you're using the latest version of the google php client. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/